# How can I use web.config value in switch case in C# without if , else loop "A constant value is expected."

Tags: c#, web-config, switch-statement, constants

Below is switch case

```
switch (strID)
{
    case ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key1"].ToString():
        Label1.Visible = true;
        break;
    case ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key2"].ToString():
        Label2.Visible = true;
        break;
    case ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key3"].ToString():
        Label3.Visible = true;
        break;
    default:
        Label1.Visible = true;
        break;
}
```

But it gives error **"A constant value is expected."**

I know that you can't have variables in the switch statement.But is any way ?

Comment: what is strid inside your switch

Comment: This should help http://stackoverflow.com/q/9004811

Comment: Possible duplicate of [switch statement: "a constant value is expected"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004811/switch-statement-a-constant-value-is-expected)

Answer (score 3):

You can use only constant value in case statement.

Better you can use if statement e.g.

```
if(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key1"].ToString() == strID)
{
   Label1.Visible = true;
}
else if(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key2"].ToString() == strID)
{
   Label2.Visible = true;
}
```

.
.
.
.
.
.
.

```
else
{
    //default
}
```

Comment: But I cant use if as I have to change very big change in current scenario

Comment: It would not be possible in switch case statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can have variables in `switch's CASE` statements. But, that must be a compile time constants i.e. `const' variable.

`CASE` statements need to be constant; by having them be constant it allows the statement to be much more heavily optimised. `Switch` will generate the equivalent of a hash table with the case statement values as keys. That approach couldn't be used if the values can change.

**Values from `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` are decided at run-time.** So you can not use it in `Switch's CASE` statements.

You can use `if.. else` statements as alternative solution.

See - [C# switch statement limitations - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44905/c-sharp-switch-statement-limitations-why)

Answer (score -1):

Assign the 3 values from Web.Config file to 3 different constants like `const string key1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key1"].ToString()` and use them in the cases inside switch instead of giving `ConfigurationManager.Appsettings["Key1"].ToString();`

Comment: switch statement not support variable also

Comment: No. Don't declare it as a variable, instead declare it as a constant. Please use the code below:
const string key1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key1"].ToString();
const string key2 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key2"].ToString();
const string key3 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key3"].ToString():
switch (strID)
{case key1:
        Label1.Visible = true;
        break;
    case key2:
        Label2.Visible = true;
        break;
    case key3:
        Label3.Visible = true;
        break;
    default:
        Label1.Visible = true;
        break;}